# Twilio Outgoing Call - Twiml url

Tags: twilio

in the basic Twilio outgoing call, there is one parameter to be set which is the url, like this example:

```
call = client.calls.create(to="+14085551234",  # Any phone number
                       from_="+12125551234", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                       url="TwiML-app-url")
```

Here is the TwiML file that is being passed in my url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="**my-ruby-script**" method="get">
        <Say>Please choose a number then press the pound sign</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

How can I handle the action with a ruby script? The ruby script needs to get the digit that is inputed by the user, then generate a new TwiML response based on that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

In order to do this you'll want to make sure your ruby script is available via publicly accessible URL. Since you specified `GET` as the method for your action Twilio will send the digits the user pressed in the query string in the parameter named `Digits`. Then you can [use the Ruby helper library to generate the TwiML](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby#getting-started-with-twiml) you want to respond with.

You didn't mention if you were using a framework so I'll show a snippet using Sinatra but the general idea would apply in other frameworks as well.

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'sinatra'

get '/process_gather' do
  # params['Digits'] <- here is where the button the user pressed will be stored. 
  # You can do a conditional check here as you see fit.
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say 'hello there', voice: 'alice'
  end

  response.text
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! one more question, should the "action=" tag inside the gather verb be equal to the url of my ruby script? I can't seem to link the TwiML file to my ruby script even though it is publicly accessible

Comment: Yes, it should be URL to of your ruby script. If Twilio is having trouble accessing you may be able to find out a bit more information by looking at what error is occurring in your app monitor: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts/